# Добавление активити в манифест

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, у меня неординарный вопрос.
Имеется апи от твиттера.
Я его интегрирую в приложение. На одной из стадий появляется такая ошибка

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {/com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Как я понял надо добавить активити в манифест, что я и сделал

```
 <activity android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" />
```

Но ошибка никуда не пропала. Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: А приложение Twitter стоит у вас в аппарате?

Comment: Приложение не установлено

Comment: Тогда установите - должно помочь

Comment: это то понятно, но по тз подразумевается что функционал должен работать и без приложения twitter.

Comment: тогда ищите другой API, этот подразумевает наличие твиттера

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902748/fabric-twitter-login-android-throwing-errors      немного погуглив нашел похожий случай, там вроде простым доабвлением активити в манифест удалось решить проблему, почему же у меня это не срабатывает?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58183/discussion-between-nikita-and-barmaley).